# Updating dob field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a `dob` field in varchar.

Currently `dob` field is mixed with 2 date formats

```
19701123
22/11/1986
```

Format: `YYYYMMDD`

Format: `DD/MM/YYYY`

How do I convert it to standard MySQL Date?

Comment: USE :`CONVERT(DATETIME,ColName)`

Comment: You can use `FROM_UNIXTIME()` to convert format.

Comment: @JaydipJ Post answer with working example